# Error log in foreach is filling up exim mail queue

Tags: php, foreach, error-handling, exim

Help!

I stupidly put an error log in an foreach with the option to send an email rather than writing to a log file (blaming the Friday brain) and after already deleting over 10,000 emails from my inbox and a further 10,000 from the mail queue they’re still being added to the mail queue.

How do I stop the server from attempting to send more emails? Do I need to stop exim, wipe the queue, then start exim again?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try restarting the server? The web server, not the whole server. If it's running as a script, then kill the script.

Comment: @aynber Yeah that worked! Restarted the Exim before but not the Apache! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the web server fixed the issue based on comment above.